# Loading AmCharts with Webpack + Typescript

Tags: javascript, charts, typescript, webpack, amcharts

I'm having some serious issues getting any charting library to work with webpack + typescript. I'm working with AmCharts right now and have already had to do work on the definitions file to get module syntax recognized by the typescript compiler.

My webpack config is set up like this:

```
"resolve": {
        extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.js'],
        "alias": {
            "config": path.join(__dirname, "../app"),
            "amcharts": "amcharts3/amcharts/amcharts.js"
        }
    },
```

And in the typescript: 
`import AmCharts from "amcharts";`

Now, this all compiles as expected, but when i do a 
`console.log(AmCharts)` I am left with an empty object.

Does anyone have any experience with getting AmCharts + webpack to play nicely, or a decent alternative charting library that meets the following criteria:

1. Decent Typescript definition support
2. Configurable via JSON
3. Plays nicely with ES6/Webpack/CommonJS

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm experiencing the same problem `import AmCharts from 'amcharts3'`

I get an empty object when printing to the console, with the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: _amcharts2.default.makeChart is not a function`

**ASNWER:**

I was able to correct my issue by referencing amcharts using the window variable like so `window.AmCharts.makeChart('chartdiv', options)`

Hopefully you can use the same approach.

Comment: I ended up getting a response from the support team at amcharts. The trick was to do `externals: {"amcharts": "var AmCharts"},` in the webpack config, then actually put it in the scripts tag in your index.html. Then where necessary you are able to do `import "amcharts"` and it will work. They say that the next version of amcharts (v4?) will have ES6 support but that it is still quite a ways off. It's a shame, its one of the better charting libraries out there.

Comment: Much cleaner way of importing the library kudos

Comment: Works with `@amcharts/amcharts4`

Answer (score 0):

We use webpack + dynamic import + amChart config.

### Copy amChart dependencies to build folder

```
    new WebpackPluginCopy([
        // Coppy amChart export dependency libs
        {
            from: 'node_modules/amcharts3/amcharts/plugins/export/libs',
            ignore: ['!*.min.js'],
            to: 'js/plugins/export/libs'
        },
        {
            from: 'node_modules/amcharts3/amcharts/plugins/export/libs/pdfmake/vfs_fonts.js',
            to: 'js/plugins/export/libs/pdfmake/vfs_fonts.js'
        },
        {
            from: 'node_modules/amcharts3/amcharts/plugins/export/shapes',
            to: 'js/plugins/export/shapes'
        }]),

module: {
    rules: [
        // Load amChart export style
        {
            test: /export.css/,
            use: ['style-loader', 'postcss-loader']
        }]}
```

### Dynamically import amChart

Promise.all([

```
        //Dynamically import amchart dependencies
        import('amcharts3/amcharts/plugins/export/export.css'),
        import('amcharts3/amcharts/amcharts'),
        import('amcharts3/amcharts/serial'),
        import('amcharts3/amcharts/themes/light'),
        import('amcharts3/amcharts/plugins/export/export.min')


    ])
```

### amChart config

```
path: '/js'
```